# Getting an Index Error in Decryption Code

Tags: python

To uncover a hidden message, you take all the lines that start with the code letter, extract the last letter or punctuation character in each line, and put them together in order.

I am provided with a .txt document that is in this format:
*Filling the room up with over 300 balloons made it hard not to trip
Martha looked out to the horizon as dusk set in over the quiet island*

**I have attempted to do this with the code:**

```
letter = input('Letter: ')
hidden_message = []

with open('puzzle.txt', 'r') as file:
  file = file.read()
  for line in file:
    line = line.lower()
    line = line.strip()
    if line[0] == letter:
      hidden_message.append(line[-1])

print(''.join(hidden_message))
```

Upon running the code, I am given this error: *Traceback (most recent call last):
File "program.py", line 9, in 
if line[0] == letter:
IndexError: string index out of range*

Comment: By chance, if you have an empty string in the middle, it can cause index errors

Comment: You can debug this yourself; simply print `line` and `len(line)` the line before where the Exception happens. If the string `line` is zero length, then accessing `line[0]` gives an index error. Now add code to prevent that happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is iterating through every letter instead of line. This change in code works to get each line.

```
with open('puzzle.txt', 'r') as file:
  for line in file:
    line = line.lower()
    line = line.strip()
    if line[0] == letter:
      hidden_message.append(line[-1])
```